# Android Studio menu designer using wrong SearchView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was having an error when trying to [create a search interface in an Android App](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/search/search-dialog). The error was 'android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView'. I tracked it down to the fact that the following code was failing to cast.

```
searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).actionView as SearchView
```

The import I was using was

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

It turned out the item in the Android Studio Muenu Designer was using android.widget.SearchView, not androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.

So I changed that and it all worked.

My question is why was Android Studio using the wrong SearchView, the min API level is set to 17 so it uses comparability Libraries everywhere else.  Does this seem like a bug or is there some setting I need to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not a wrong searchView. Its not a bug. It is because of Android library shifted `appcompat` to `androidx.`
 Pleaset take a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx?gclid=CjwKCAjwyaWZBhBGEiwACslQo0FIKdUABqQdJUjOvI68RarWzuY44B8emyIQRnmZYPwKDLjb8ToZIRoCYGQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).
It automatically import androidx you can change it to appcompat.
No need to setup.